# Unable to import ParseImageView - Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse for my project. I am able to import all other classes from the parse library like

```
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseGeoPoint;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseQuery.CachePolicy;
```

I am not able to import `ParseImageView` alone.

```
import com.parse.ParseImageView;
```

Should I add any additional JAR file for that. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/releases

1.10.0

- New: ParseImageView and ParseQueryAdapter are now part of ParseUI.

The solution is the following:

- Clone the project https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android
- Import Parser-UI-widget module to your project
- compile project (': ParseUI-widget') in the dependencies of
  build.gradle

For example,

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    // Parse
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3'
    compile project(':ParseUI-Widget')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems the latest parse library doesn't have ParseImageView method.
I solved it by inputting the old version of parse library 1.3.2 into libs folder and set the dependencies as

`dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    }`

You can get old library at [their github examples.](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/MealSpotting/tree/master/libs)

Answer (score 0):

Parse is now available at [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg:%22com.parse%22%20AND%20a:%22parse-android%22).

Recommended way to add it as a dependency for your Android project is:

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.1'
}`