# I can't import com.parse.ParseImageView

Tags: parse-platform

I've been trying to import com.parse.ParseImageView so i can display image queried from parse. But I get this error in my xml file

> The following classes could not be found:
>   - com.parse.ParseImageView

Is ParseImageView no longer supported ? What is the alternative way to display image from parse database? Thanks

Comment: You might wanna take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062243/unable-to-import-parseimageview-android

Comment: I actually saw that post before I asked this question. The problem is I have to use the older version of Parse and I'm trying to avoid doing that