# Parse UI not being found when syncing gradle

Tags: android, parse-platform

[screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EKo2.png)

Hi guys!

There has been a recent problem regarding the ability to import the **ParseImageView** class in Android Studio and there is currently only one solution: [Unable to import ParseImageView - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062243/unable-to-import-parseimageview-android).

When trying this solution, it asks to download a **ParseUI-Widget** file from **github** and then import that project into my current project and then finally add a **dependency** for the ParseUI in the **build.gradle**. When attempting to **sync** the gradle, the error in the screenshot keeps on popping up no matter where I place the ParseUI-Widget file in the project file directory.

Please Help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to check.

1. Make sure that [this is the content](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android/tree/master/ParseUI-Widget) you have inside your `ParseUI-Widget`.
2. Move your `ParseUI-Widget` up one directory. This way it is the same level as `app`
3. You also need to edit your `settings.gradle`. Your settings gradle likely looks like this:

   ```
   include ':app'
   ```

   Edit it to look like this:

   ```
   include ':app', ':ParseUI-Widget'
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. You currently have ParseUI-Widget within the app/ directory. So you should be including it in your top-level settings.gradle file as `:app:ParseUI-Widget`, and within your build.gradle as `compile project(':app:ParseUI-Widget')`
2. You can also move the entire app/ParseUI-Widget directory one directory up, so that it's in the same directory, side by side with your app/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it seems you haven't imported the ParseUI-Widget module. Rather you just cloned the project from github and pasted it in your project directory structure.

What you have to do is,

1. go in your android studio project structure view,
2. right click and under new,
3. click on new module and then
4. import the ParseUI-Widget as module.

Then those dependencies are in build.  gradle will work fine.